# asp:controls transformations from html form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, controls

I have this code and I want it to transforms it to asp.net controls in label and literal ?

How?

```
` <input type="text" id="_Email" class="contact-form" name="Email" placeholder="Email address">`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular element would actually be a `TextBox` [MSDN TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx)

It would look like this `<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Email" CssClass="contact-form" />`. this would then render `<input type="text" id="_Email" class="contact-form" />`

The `Literal` control doesn't produce an HTML element and allows you to add text/html to your page and not wrap it in any other HTML.

The `Label` control actually outputs a `<span></span>` and puts your `Text` in between it.

Comment: Is there anything in asp:textbox like placeholder, except Text?

Comment: There is an asp:Placeholder controller that allows you to add other controls. So you could put a placeholder on your page and then controls inside it. Placeholder doesn't render any HTML, though it allows you to dynamically get/set controls. I.E MyPlaceholder.Controls.Add(MyTextbox)